# What is the expected length of an interval on an arc of a circle that can be constructed using exponential variates?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, expected-value

Consider a circle $S$ of length $\theta$. Now suppose, we delete an interval $I$ of length $|I|$ (I'll drop the $|\cdot|$ notation for length and directly write $I$) from it.

Now on $S-I$, I choose a point $U$ uniformly at random and construct around $U$, another interval $J_{U}$ having it's length distributed as a $\min(J^{+}+J^{-}, \theta)$ where $J^{+}$ and $J^{-}$ are iid exponential$(1)$ variates.

**What is the expected length of this interval constructed**? i.e. what is $E(J_{U})?$

What I did was I considered one end  point of $I$ to be the origin(or the pole/reference point of the circle with coordinates measured in anticlockwise direction) and then it is equivalent to constructing $J$ around $0$ and the whole interval $I$ shifted anticlocklwise by $U$. Then $J^{+}$ can be considered to be measured in anticlockwise direction and $J^{-}$ to be measured in clockwise direction about $0$.

Using the above, we get $E\left(\min(U,J^{+})+\min(\theta-I-U,J^{-})\right)$.

Now by conditioning on $U=u$, \begin{align*}
    &U\int_{U}^{\infty}e^{-z}\,dz+\int_{0}^{U}ze^{-z}\,dz +(\theta-I-U)\int_{\theta-I-U}^{\infty}e^{-z}dz+\int_{0}^{\theta-I-U}ze^{-z}\\
    &=(1-e^{-U})+(1-e^{-(x-U)})\end{align*}

Now taking the expectation in $U$, we get $\frac{2x-2(1-e^{-x})}{x}$ where $x=\theta - I$ .

Is the above correct or am I missing some more terms?

Or even going a step backwards, is the conditional expectation of the length of $J_{u}$ given $U=u$ correct?

**i.e. if $u$ is a fixed point on $S-I$, then what is the expected length of an interval (distributed as $\min(J^{+}+J^{-},\theta)$ for iid expo$(1)$) that can be constructed about $U$ on the arc $S-I$**?

EDIT: I am now sure that I am missing more details. For example, what if $J^{+}>I+u$ and $\theta-J^{-}\leq J^{+}$, then I am certainly ending up ignoring some parts.

Can someone please help me with this.

Edit: **To be more explicit, in words, what I want to do is :- We are looking to find the expected length of the interval $I'$ that is built outside of $I$ when we imagine $I$ to be part of the original circle.**

This is the mental image I had while doing the problem
[image]

**EDIT** Additionally in the paper, the description given (**this was the initial question which attracted close votes for needing more details**) that if $I'$ is an independent interval(arc) having length law $\min(J^{+}+J^{-},\theta)$ built around $0$ and if $I$ is a fixed interval not containing $0$ then note the following definition $I\cap_{0} I'=\{x\in I': x\nleftrightarrow 0 \,\text{within}\, I'\setminus I\}$. Then $H_{0}(I):=E(I\cap_{0}I')$ and $UH_{0}=E(H_{0}(I-U))$ for an uniform $U$ variate on the circle.

It is this $UH_{0}$ and $(UH_{0})$ that I want to calculate. It is also claimed later in the paper(page 23) that $E(H_0(I-u)|U=u)$ equals the expected length of part of the interval $I'$ that can be constructed around $u$ outside $I^c$.

This is all the details I have.

Comment: Clarity pays more than bounties. "a circle S of length θ". Is this the same as a a circle of radius $\theta/(2 \pi)$? An "interval" is an arc ? So why not speak of an arc of length $A=\theta- I$ ? What is the sense defining $J^+$ and $J^-$ , why not just a single Erlang variable? Further, the length seems unrelated to the $S-I$ circle-arc ... and to the randomly select point.. Worse, why are we speaking of circles, if all the explanation seems to aplly to a line? All sounds rather senseless to me.

Comment: I'll try to answer your comment in an one by one fashion. A circle of length $\theta$ means a circle of radius $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}$. An interval is an arc and I don't see the issue here as in the context of a circle what else could it mean?. The $J^{+}$ and $J^{-}$ variates are to help think about $J^{+}$ being measured in an anticlock direction and $J^{-}$ being measured in clockwise direction so that the interval(arc) is of length $J^{+}+J^{-}$.  @leonbloy

Comment: @leonbloy Secondly, to me atleast (and also to Amir Dembo and others apparently who wrote the paper) computing expectations(also conditioned on other things possibly) of exponential might have been easier than that of an Erland due to Memoryless property.

Comment: @leonbloy Thirdly, if the length did not depend on the uniform shift, then the expectation would just be that of $J^{+}+J^{-}\wedge \theta- I$ which it certainly is not the case here since it is $2(1-e^{-x})+xe^{-x}$.

Comment: @leonbloy Lastly, It is true that after deleting the interval $I$, we apparently end up with a line case. But we are looking to find the expected length of the interval $I'$ that is built outside of $I$ when we imagine $I$ to be part of the original circle. I take this point and I'll include this in the question. In any case, your comment could have been much less rude.

Comment: @leonbloy It does not reduce to the linear case, as if $J^{+}$ exceeds $I+u$ for example and if $J^{-}$ is less than $\theta-J^{+}$, still we have some portion ($J^{+}\to \theta-J^{-}$) that has to be additionally taken into account apart from $U$.